# Create quote programmatically doesn't work

Tags: magento

I need to create a quote programmatically. It works if the sales_flat_quote table is empty. If it's not empty then it doesn't work. This is my code so far in indexAction().

```
$customer_id = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getId();
$product_id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('product_id');
$store_id = Mage:app()->getStore()->getId();
$customerObj = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($customer_id);
$quoteObj = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->assignCustomer($customerObj);
$storeObj = $quoteObj->getStore()->load($store_id);
$quoteObj->setStore($storeObj);
$productModel = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
$productObj = $productModel->load($product_id);
$quoteItem = Mage::getModel('sales/quote_item')->setProduct($productObj);
$quoteItem->setQuote($quoteObj);
$quoteItem->setQty('1');
$quoteItem->setStoreId($store_id);
$quoteObj->addItem($quoteItem);
$quoteObj->setStoreId($store_id);
$quoteObj->collectTotals();
$quoteObj->save();
$this->_redirect('checkout/cart/');
```

Any idea why the sales_flat_quote table must be empty in order for this to work?

Comment: "it doesn't work" is rarely enough information to track something like this down.  Error messages, expected behavior vs. actual behavior, etc.

Comment: By "it doesn't work" I meant, the item is not listed in shopping cart (shopping cart is showing empty). The new record got added in sales_flat_quote_* tables, but again, the shopping cart is empty. But if I truncate all the sales_flat_quote_* tables, then the item got listed in shopping cart. If there were error message or exception, I should have known what the cause is. Currently, I'm still trying at which point to debug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like the frontend cart code can't connect your quote with a specific customer.  I'd start debugging in the

```
app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Model/Cart.php
```

file.  Specifically the `getQuote` and `saveQuote` methods.  Determine why Magento is loading an empty quote on the frontend, and the problem should be illuminated.

Based on the comments below, it looks like you're instantiating your code object here

```
$quoteObj = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->assignCustomer($customerObj);
```

This creates a new quote model object each time.  If you want to save an existing quote, you need to load it instead of creating a new quote model object each time. You could load an existing quote by id with the following

```
Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->load($quote_id);
```

It also appears the quote object has a `loadByCustomerId` method, so you might have some luck with something like this

```
$quoteObj = Mage::getModel('sales/quote');
$quoteObj = $quoteObj->loadByCustomerId($quoteObj, $customer_id);
```

Comment: I found it. It because the $quoteObj->save(); keeps creating a new record in sales_flat_quote table. Is there a way for $quoteObj->save(); to update current record instead of creating a new record?

Comment: @user1576748 Updated my answer with some information that (hopefully) helps.  Working directly with quotes is one of the more advanced Magento topics/tasks, and will require some programming legwork/research.  Good luck!

Comment: No worry. I solved it with isObjectNew() method. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Dear, Alan,can you help me regarding below thing: assign old sales quote to new quote...

Comment: @AmitBera : Do you have the solutions now ?